# How to write a migration to convert an already-present association to optional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a few `belongs_to` migrations created & migrated but I see now that in Rails 5, the default behavior is `required: true` which I do not want.

How can I write a simple migration to convert that to `optional: true`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`change_column_null`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_null) method for that:

```
def change
  change_column_null :table, :column, true
end
```

`change_column_null` is reversible, if you need to rollback the value will be false (or true depending on the case).

---

Answering to your question *If I simply add optional: true in the model, will it work?*. No, if you have a foreign key with `nullable` value `NOT NULL` you're going to face an error everytime you try to create a record without that value, e.g:

A table comments with a relationship to users:

```
                                                              Table "public.comments"
   Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |               Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('comments_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 description | character varying              |           |          |                                      | extended |              |
 user_id     | bigint                         |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              |
 created_at  | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              |
 updated_at  | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_comments_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_RUSSIA_TERRORIST_STATE" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

When you instantiate a new record, Rails will tell nothing about the missing foreign key:

```
foo = Comment.new(description: :foo)
foo.valid? # true
foo.save
# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

But if you try to persist the record, you're going to get an `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation` error because of the `not-null` constraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using this and will accept this as answer as soon as it is verified but I needed to ask, is that the only way or can I do it with `change` too as I thought it was the syntax followed in rails 5, right?

Comment: One more question (if you can please guide): if I simply add `optional: true` in the model (where I say `belongs_to`), will it work? i.e. will it handle the case where I want to create the model without that id.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `change`, this is just another way to make a reversible migration. No, `belongs_to` doesn't prevent your database to raise an error when the value for the foreign key is null. It just skips the presence validation when creating a relationship.