# Rails migration change constraint on foreign key column - workaround?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, migration

I tried to change a constraint on a foreign key column such that it would accept a null value too (the root of a tree structure doesn't have a parent)

```
class ChangeColumnNullValid < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column_null(:articles, :parent_article_id, true)
  end
end
```

Not even

```
$ rails db:rollback
```

does work ! Obviously major migration f**k-up !

Obviously Rails doesn't like that.

Is there another workaround than to delete the column and add the foreign key again?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve is not clear. Can you explain what parts you did and what you wanted because it is not clear at what step things went astray. If that my help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396128/how-to-write-a-migration-to-convert-an-already-present-association-to-optional

Comment: Hello. The ```articles``` class is self joined and not only reflexive but nestable. Tree-nodes. The root should be allowed not to have a parent because it has none. 

Best wishes

Comment: Yeah what you want is even clearer now but I meant to ask that how your solution failed. What exactly happened with your migration. AS far as I know, this worked for me previously but if it did not in your case, I am as interested in figuring out the issue as yourself.