# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have upgraded rails application from rails 4 to 5.2. Getting errors while running Rspec's.
I have the below line in my code. I have tried to add `required: true` or `optional: true` parameter, but it's not working

```
class abc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application_version
  # Rest of the code
end
```

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
        Validation failed: Application version can't be blank

Comment: I know you've mentioned it, but its surprising that even `belongs_to :application_version, optional: true` did not work!

Comment: Can you add snippet of your test? And what is currently in your model? Including any validations that you have, ie: model and db. Did the migration have a null constraint? Does the model have a presence validation for `application_version_id`?

Comment: I guess what you mean to say is that you added this line directly and not the migration. You have your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59396128/10313894